# Can remove Nulls from Database using C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can we remove the Nulls from the Table Columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following will work

```
DELETE FROM Table 
WHERE ColumnName IS NULL;
GO
```

The C# tag throws me. You can execute this command from C# using the [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class.

```
UPDATE Table 
SET ColumnName = 'DefaultValue' 
WHERE ColumnName IS NULL
```

Comment: I want to make the Null Values to some default values using C# .

Answer (score 1):

Use `SqlCommand` class of C# to update your Table. something like as follows

```
    try
    {
        string yourSQL= "UPDATE YourTable SET ColumnName = 'YourDefaultValue' WHERE ColumnName IS NULL";

        SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(yourSQL, YourConnection);
        UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // Display error
    }
```